# How to add a new file type to vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have a project which uses Mustache template engine and the file extension name is `xxx.ms`. I want to make this syntax highlighting. Then I did the following.

I install the `Handlebars` extension of vscode. And edit the config file `~/.vscode/extensions/andrejunges.Handlebars/syntaxes/handlebars.tmLanguage` as the following.[image]

But although I restart vscode, it still doesn't work. So I wonder how does vscode detect a file extension and use the corresponding extension installed to highlight the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the file extension also to the `package.json` file which is located in the root folder of the extension. Look for something like this:

```
"contributes": {
    "languages": [
        {
            "id": "mylanguage",
            "extensions": [
                ".mylang",
                ".myl" // add the file extension here
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open settings.json and add:

```
"files.associations": {   
    "*.ms": "handlebars",  
}
```